# MVC create nested WebGrid from two queries

Tags: model-view-controller, nested, webgrid

I want to create nested WebGrid using data from joined queries.
I prefer to create models for queries and fill the data in two lists which I will use in View . I am not sure I access to data correct.
Here are queries:

```
public DataSet Get_Docs()
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select "+
        "d.SN, d.date_d, d.DOC_NUM, o.NAME OsnName " +
        "from docs d " +
        "left join opers o on d.osn = o.SN " +
        "where d.TIP = 2 and d.ISCHANGED = 0 and d.BASAOUT = 2 " +
        "order by d.DT desc", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
 public DataSet Get_Items(int? DocSN)
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
                "select i.sn,i.docsn,s.NOMNO StokNomNo,s.NAME StokName,i.kol, "+
                "IIF((i.kol is null)or(i.kol = 0)or(i.sumtotal is null)or(i.sumtotal = 0), 0, round(i.sumtotal / i.kol, 2)) PRICE, " +
                "i.SUMTOTAL " +
                "from items i " +
                "left join STOKI s on i.StokSN = s.SN where i.DocSN=@DocSN", con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocSN", DocSN);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

my model

```
         public class DocsVM
            {   public Int32? SN { get; set; }
                public string OsnName { get; set; }
            }
     public class ItemsVM
        {   public Int32? SN { get; set; }
            public Int32? DocSN { get; set; }
            public double SumTotal { get; set; }
        }
     public class OrderVM
        {       public List<DocsVM> DocsVML { get; set; }
                public List<ItemsVM> ItemsVML { get; set; }
        }
```

My controller:

```
 database_Access_layer.db dblayer = new database_Access_layer.db();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DataSet ds = dblayer.Get_Docs();
            List<OrderVM> allOrder = new List<OrderVM>();
            List<DocsVM> docsList = new List<DocsVM>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                docsList.Add(new DocsVM
                {
                    SN = Convert.ToInt32(dr["SN"]),
                    OsnName = Convert.ToString(dr["OsnName"]),
                });
                DataSet dsItems = dblayer.Get_Items(Convert.ToInt32(dr["SN"]));
                List<ItemsVM> itemsList = new List<ItemsVM>();
                foreach (DataRow drItems in dsItems.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    itemsList.Add(new ItemsVM
                    {
                        SN = Convert.ToInt32(drItems["SN"]),
                        DocSN = Convert.ToInt32(drItems["DocSN"]),
                        SumTotal = Convert.ToDouble(drItems["SumTotal"])
                    });
                }
                allOrder.Add(new OrderVM { DocsVML=docsList,ItemsVML=itemsList});    
            }
            return View(allOrder);
```

and My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AllForMarket.eu.ViewModel.OrderVM>
@{ WebGrid mainGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model);}
@mainGrid.GetHtml(
                    htmlAttributes: new { @id = "WebGrid", @class = "Grid" },
                    columns: mainGrid.Columns(
                             mainGrid.Column("DocsVML.SN", "SN"),
                             mainGrid.Column("DocsVML.OsnName", "username"),
                             mainGrid.Column(format: item => {
                                     WebGrid subGrid = new WebGrid(source: item.ItemsVML);
                                     return subGrid.GetHtml(
                                         htmlAttributes: new { id = "subT" },
                                         columns: subGrid.Columns(
                                             subGrid.Column("ItemsVML.SN", "item.SN"),
                                             subGrid.Column("ItemsVML.DocSN", "DocSN"),
                                             subGrid.Column("ItemsVML.SumTotal", "sum")));
                                 })))
```

A have an error. VS says:Column "DocsVML.SN" does not exist.'. I have data, and I can not access the fields. Maybe my error is in OrderVM ViewModel? please help!

Comment: This helps and solves my needs to some extent, but I want to use WebGrid - so Question is open https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/166399/Nested-GridView-or-Repeater-Table-structure-in-ASPNet-MVC/